# Changing default REST actions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, customization

I want to be able to change the default mapping of actions with RESTful url and type of request.

For example,

After adding `map.resources :fruits` in the routes, by default, sending a `GET` request to `/fruits/:id` calls `show` action in `fruits` controller. However, I would like to call a custom action, say `display`, in the `fruits` controller instead of `show` action. How do I do it? This has to be a route configuration.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but please be aware that Rails' "RESTful routing" has nothing to do with REST. Pretty URIs are orthogonal to REST. There's no such thing as a "RESTful URL". If you're interested in REST, please read into it some more - Fielding's dissertation is the authoritative source, or you can browse some of the REST explanations on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to read this page:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

It explains in detail all aspects related to routing.

Using :path_names you can customize the new and edit generated paths. If you want to change `GET /fruits/:id` from activating the `show` action to activating a `display` action, then the change is invisible to the user. And you would be deviating from the flow with no apparent reason.

Comment: There are actually decent reasons to do this if you're using nested resources, particularly deeply nested resources. At some point you end up with massive controller proliferation by accepting the defaults, and overriding them allows you to keep the nested structure while sending multiple resources to the same controller. I find this particularly useful when you would otherwise end up with a parent controller that has only an index action and nothing else but more complex child resources.